# Como enviar valores de checkbox por formulario en MVC

Tags: asp.net, mvc, entity-framework, linq, razor

les comento, tengo una tabla creada con datos de mercaderias (ID, Nombre, Tipo, etc) acompañados de un checkbox por cada fila. Lo que quiero hacer es marcar los checkbox de los producto que quiero ver mas detalladamente y que al hacer click  en un boton se envie a un controller y se visualice en otra vista.

Si alguien podria ayudarme, gracias.

```
<div class="container">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Detail", "Mercaderia", new { }, FormMethod.Get, new { @class = "container form-inline" }))
        {
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                <tr class="table-secondary">
                    <td class="info">Mercaderia ID</td>
                    <td class="info">Mercaderia Descripcion</td>
                    <td class="info">Mercaderia Cantidad</td>
                </tr>
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@item.MercaderiaID</td>
                        <td>@item.MercaderiaDescripcion</td>
                        <td>@item.MercaderiaCantidad</td>
                        <td>@Html.CheckBox(@item.MercaderiaDescripcion, false, new { @value = item.MercaderiaDescripcion})  Select</td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="View"/>
        }
    </div>
```

Esta seria mi vista la cual al hacer click en el checkbox y darle al boton submit tendria que mandarme a otra vista donde pueda ver en otra tabla todo lo que seleccione con mas detalle que los que me muestra en esta vista. El problema lo tengo con lo que tiene que hacer la logica y el controlador de esa vista.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido, podrías mostrar un ejemplo de como lo estas haciendo, para poder brindarte una mejor ayuda.

Comment: Ahi edite mi publicacion y lo puse dentro,gracias

Comment: Tengo que hacer la vista y la logica pero no tengo idea de como hacerlo. La idea es por ejemplo, si yo en la tabla selecciono jabon en polvo, dulce de leche y queso. En la vista siguiente (Detail) tendria que mostrarme todos los detalles de las productos que seleccione. No se si se logra entender lo que quiero hacer.

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes usar Jquery para capturar los valores de los diferentes inputs que quieres mandar a la otra vista, y utilizando la función $.Ajax, te dejo un ejemplo:

```
'use strict';
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var botonPrincipal = $("#nextBtn");
        botonPrincipal.click(function () {
            if (!$("#primeTab").css("display:block")) {
            /*Obtencion de los datos de los campos correspondiente a el primer modúlo*/
                var datosIndicadores = { };
                datosIndicadores.idCampo = $("#ID_CAMPO").val();
                datosIndicadores.categoriaIndicador = $("#CATEGORIA_INDICADOR").val();
                datosIndicadores.idContrato = $( #ID_CONTRATO").val();
                datosIndicadores.campoPeriodo = $("#PERIODO").val();
                datosIndicadores.campoValor = $("#VALOR").val();
                /*Fin de la obtencion de los datos de los campos correspondiente a el primer modúlo*/
                $.ajax({
//Aca Va la ruta de tu controlador que redigira a la vista
                    url: "/IndicadoresSST/PrimerIndicador",
                    method: "POST",
                    data: '{Ind:'+ JSON.stringify(datosIndicadores) +'}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        console.log(JSON.stringify(datosIndicadores));
                        console.log("Enviando datos");
                    },
                    success: function (resultado, data) {
                        console.log(resultado);
                        console.log(data);
                        alert("Datos Ingresados de manera satisfactoria...")
                    },
                    error: function (err) { 
                        console.log(err);
                        console.log('Ocurrió un error al acceder a la información');
                    },
                    timeout: 2000
                });

            }
        })
    });
```

Espero te ayude, Exitos!
Para que tengas en cuenta en el parámetro `data:` de $.ajax el campo `Ind` corresponde aun valor que mi controlador esta esperando, espero no te confundas.

Comment: Hola, estuve viendo el codigo y tengo una duda en la siguiente linea

if (!$("#primeTab").css("display:block")) 

Esto detecta y valida un checkbox? Por que necesitaria que me tome todos los checkbox que esten seleccionados y son varios en mi ejercicio. 
Al mandarlos como los recibiria mi ActionController para validar y que devuelva una nueva vista con solo los que selecciones?

Comment: No, realmente es un ejemplo, lo que hace es que cuando el id primeraTab, en sus caracteristica de css es diferente de `display: block` entonces haga lo que está dentro del if.

Comment: Buenisimo, y como haria en el caso que tenga por ejemplo tres checkbox seleccionados, si le pongo la misma id me guardaria los datos de los tres o solo de uno?

Y otra cosa, como me tendria que recibir el ActionController en parametros para que pueda pasarmelo a la vista

Comment: Puede que me equivoque pero si le colocas el mis id es decir `<checkbox id=" ">` en consola te mostrara que el atributo no es único, así que lo más probable es que solo te tome un valor.

Answer (score 0):

El atributo del name del control de html lo mapea MVC en un listado dentro del controller, tanto para checkboxes, radiobuttons o incluso textboxes

En el controller seria algo asi ya que el nombre de la propiedad lo agarra como el name en html:

```
public  ActionResult Detail(string[] MercaderiaDescripcion)
{

}
```

Comment: Por favor lee [answer], edita y considera agregar una explicación, pues solo responder con código se considera de baja calidad